# Numerical evaluation of $\sum_{N=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{\Gamma(N+1)^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{N}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, gamma-function

Given 
$$S=\sum_{N=1}^\infty\left(\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(N+1)^2}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{N}}$$
Using the Carleman inequality, I got for S:
$$S\le\dfrac{1}{6}e\pi^2$$
Using numerical calculation I suppose that the value of 
S is less than $3.2$.
Is it possible to have a better vaule or eventually a better iniquality for S?

Comment: $3.096724440$ is better

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html) easily eats $\texttt{sumnum(n=1,exp(-2*lngamma(n+1)/n))}$ giving $3.09672480007969548412482407485480297466758470220341\ldots$