# Calculating $S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{\Gamma^2(n+1)}\right)^{{1}/{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, gamma-function, riemann-integration, zeta-functions

I tried to find the answer for the question: [Numerical evaluation of $\sum_{N=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{\Gamma(N+1)^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{N}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3015668/numerical-evaluation-of-sum-n-1-infty-left-frac1-gamman12-right).
I think my result is $4$ times than the expected value. Is this accidental and my solution is not correct? Does my solution have theoretical or some inattention fault?

The solution is:

$S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{\Gamma^2(n+1)}\right)^{{1}/{n}}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n!^2)}\right)^{{1}/{n}}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \prod\limits_{k=1}^n k^{-2/n}$

$S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty e^{\frac{2}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \ln(\frac{1}{k})} $

From the exponent we get:

${\frac{2}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \ln(\frac{1}{k})}={\frac{2}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \ln(\frac{n}{k} \frac{1}{n})}=\frac{2}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \ln\frac{n}{k}+\frac{2}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \ln \frac{1}{n}$

The first term of the exponent is Riemann sum so we get:

$2\int\limits _0^1\ln\frac{1}{x} dx= 2$

Put back into the sum:

$S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty e^{2-\frac{2}{n} n \ln{n}}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac {e^{2}}{n^2}=\zeta(2)e^2 $

Comment: Please write an *informative* (not generic) title so people can find this problem if they happen to have the exact same one.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, Thank you for the comment I will do my questions according to your suggestion, regards.

Comment: You can still edit the question title now, which is vague.

Comment: Replacing the Riemann sum by an integral is approximate and works well only for large $n$'s.

Comment: IOW, you proved that $$\left(\Gamma(n+1)\right)^{-2/n}\sim e^2/n^2$$ when $n\to\infty$, which says nothing about the actual value of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\Gamma(n+1)\right)^{-2/n}$$

Comment: With the *Carleman inequality* and $\,x\geq 0\, $ you get $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{\sqrt[k]{k!^2}} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sqrt[k]{\frac{x^1}{1^2}\dots \frac{x^k}{k^2}} \leq e \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k^2}$$  and it is very unlikely that there is an exact formula.

Comment: @useer90369 Thanks, it was used in the original question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3015668/numerical-evaluation-of-sum-n-1-infty-left-frac1-gamman12-right.

Comment: So, it would be good if you write what you like to know. Because the "first term of the exponent" is a Riemann sum but leads only to the integral for $n\to\infty$, means: you cannot use it here.

Comment: @useer90369, I think that you give me the answer now for my question. Thank you, regards.

Comment: You are welcome. :)

Comment: @user90369 You ought to post your comment as an answer, so that the question no longer shows up on the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*At the suggestion of* saulspatz *I write my comment as an answer.*

The "first term of the exponent" is a Riemann sum but leads only to the integral for $n\to\infty$, means: you cannot use it here.